# How to set Azure release pipeline release name in azure app service appsettings.json

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need to set the Azure pipeline release name to an Azure app service appsettings.json file for the application to display. I am using the release pipeline classic. I know there is a default variable  called "Release.ReleaseName" in the pipeline. How to set its value to the application appsettings.json before deployment?

[Release.ReleaseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) - Example: Release-47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **Replace Token task** from [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are my steps, you could refer to them:

Json file:

```
{
  "Position": {
    "Title": "Editor",
    "Name": "xx"
  },
  "MyKey":  "#{Release.ReleaseName}#",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Replace Token task sample:

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: 'Folder Path'
    targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

Then the variables in `Appsettings.json` will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you Fairy, this is promising. I just need to get that extension and try it out. So it will replace "#{Release.ReleaseName}#" with the release pipeline's default variable Release.ReleaseName value?

Comment: All was good except I had to use unzip and zip tasks for the artifacts before and after this task.